# Issue when testing child controller that has a method defined in parent controller

Tags: karma-jasmine

I am trying to test a simple controller variable but my controller has a method which calls parent controller and showing this error.How do i solve this error.
here is the test file

```
describe('SigninController', function () {
    beforeEach(module("app.website"));
    var controller,scope,parentscope;
    var $scope,$controller,$parentScope,$parentcontroller,$mdToast;
    window.ga = function() {};

    beforeEach(module("ngMaterial"));
    beforeEach(module("ngAnimate"));
    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('SigninController',{$scope : scope});
    }));

    describe('simple program', function () {
        it('should say true equals true', function () {
            expect(scope.isShowProgress).toEqual(false);
        });
    });
});
```

TypeError: $scope.setMetaInfo is not a function
        at init (public_html/components/myaccount/signin/controllers/signin_controller.js:77:20)
        at new  (public_html/components/myaccount/signin/controllers/signin_controller.js:65:9)
        at Object.instantiate (public_html/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5055:14)
        at $controller (public_html/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10975:28)
        at public_html/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2308:14
        at Object. (Unit%20Tests/demotest.js:17:22)
        at Object.invoke (public_html/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5040:19)
        at Object.WorkFn (public_html/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3182:20)
    Error: Declaration Location
        at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (public_html/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3145:25)
        at Suite. (Unit%20Tests/demotest.js:15:16)
        at Unit%20Tests/demotest.js:7:1
Chrome 59.0.3071 (Mac OS X 10.11.6): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.204 secs)
Chrome 59.0.3071 (Mac OS X 10.11.6): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.221 secs / 0.204 secs)

Answer (score 0):

```
var MainTodayCtrl,
    rootScope,
    scope;

// Initialize the controller and a mock scope
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
    rootScope = $rootScope.$new(); // root for parent controller
    $controller('MainCtrl', { $scope: rootScope });

    // then your MainCtrl will alter that scope
    // for the child controller you need a "derived" scope
    scope = rootScope.$new();

    // now business as usua
    MainTodayCtrl = $controller('MainTodayCtrl', {
        $scope: scope
        // place here mocked dependencies
    });
}));
```